# how to execute two commands stored in one bash variable

Tags: bash

Let's say there is one bash variable

> run1="date"

I need to execute `date` by

> ${run1}

And it works, since it prints current time. But if I put two commands in the variable,

> run2="date; echo foo"

I can't execute the commands stored in variable `run2`, since `${run2}` complains

> date;: command not found

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
eval ${run2}
```

This should help.

Comment: it works... maybe i am inquisitive, but can you explain why it works for ``run1`` but not for ``run2``...

Comment: Because it is quoted, the semi-colon is part of the first word after quote removal, not a syntactic element to separate two commands.

Answer (score 2):

Try `eval "${run2}"`. That will interpret the variable as a sequence of commands to be run.